# C# Linq Join 2 ObservableCollections into new one

Tags: c#, linq, observablecollection

I've got 3 classes (T1 and T2 data come from an SQLite file)

**T1 (EmployeeEntity --> Id, FirstName, LastName, DepartmentFK)** << DepartmentKey is a foreign key to T2.Id

**T2 (DepartmentEntity --> Id, Department)**

**T3 (DepartmentEmployee --> Id, FirstName, LastName, DepartmentFK, Department)** << Id should be the same as T1.Id (make saving changes back much easier)

In my viewmodel I create a new ObservableCollection `public ObservableCollection<DepartmentEmployee> EmployeesView` and would like to fill these with data from 2 SQLite tables and this is how I do it:

```
    get
    {
        var t1 = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeEntity>(_emp.GetAll().ToObservable());
        var t2 = new ObservableCollection<DepartmentEntity>(_dep.GetAll().ToObservable());
        var result = t1.Join(t2, t => t.DepartmentFK, t => t.Id, (EmployeeEntity, DepartmentEntity) =>
        {
            var t3 = _mapper.Map<EmployeeEntity, DepartmentEmployee>(EmployeeEntity);
            t3 = _mapper.Map(DepartmentEntity, t3);
            return t3;
        });
        _employeesview = result.ToObservable();
        return _employeesview;
    }
```

This works for my View (I can display FirstName, LastName and the appropriate Department (based on the foreign key)) but when I try to save my changes back it changes the wrong record. My problem is this:

T1

```
1 - Test - User - 2
2 - Another - User -3
3 - Third - User - 1
```

T2

```
1 - Development
2 - HR
3 - Production
```

results in this

T3

```
2 - Test - User - 2 - HR
3 - Another - User - 3 - Production
1 - Third - User - 1 - Development
```

so it "kills" my employee Id and replaces it with the Id of the department. So how can I fix this?

---

add. Info:
these are my mappings I made

```
        cfg.CreateMap<DepartmentEntity, Departments>();
        cfg.CreateMap<Departments, DepartmentEntity>();
        cfg.CreateMap<EmployeeEntity, DepartmentEmployee>();
        cfg.CreateMap<DepartmentEmployee, EmployeeEntity>();
        cfg.CreateMap<DepartmentEntity, DepartmentEmployee>();
```

Answer (score 0):

stupid me, I had to put the "Id" on ignore in my mapping

-->

```
cfg.CreateMap<DepartmentEntity, DepartmentEmployee>().ForMember(dest => dest.DepartmentFK, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id)).ForMember(dest => dest.Id, act => act.Ignore());
```

did the trick :)